# Viewing stdout from Google Cloud

Tags: python, ssh, cloud, stdout

I am just getting started with google cloud so I could use some help. I am running a python script on a google cloud VM and I would like to somehow view the stdout without having to open the SSH and typing tmux attach every time. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have no idea where to start from :(